# Delphi 6 : Error invoking Machine Code when referencing a .Net Assembly via COM

Tags: .net, delphi, com, machine-code

We have an application written in **Delphi 6** in which we generate and execute machine code for maths operations (Input a string -> output machine code -> invoke lots and lots of times). This has been working well for many (many) years.

We recently added some functionality written in C# and accessed via COM.
Accessing the new functionality works fine.

If there is an error in the calculation (say out of range or, div by 0) we are having problems.

If we have *not* created an instance of the COM object [ **Note:** we are not using the COM object here, only calling `CreateOleObject()`  to create it], and then input an invalid calculation (say, '1/0') we get an exception that we can trap and deal with.

However, once we have created the COM object we no longer get the Div/0 exception. 
 - First time we invoke it, we get a StackOverflow exception.
 - Second time we invoke it, we get an Access Violation exception that cannot be trapped and causes the application to crash.

- As long as there is no error in the calculation, it executes correctly.
- As long as there is no COM object created, we can invoke the invalid calculation as many times as we like and just get the Div/0 error each time
- The COM object has nothing to do with the calculations and is never invoked, it seems to be merely creating it causes the problem
- The target machine has .NET 4 Client Profile and .NET 4 Extended frameworks installed

I recognize that this is pretty far out there in terms of usage but if anyone out there has any ideas I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

**Update:** 
It turns out that we use other .Net assemblies in the application, accessing them through COM and that they do not cause a problem.  I have created 2  simple assemblies, and made them COM accessible. One targets .Net 2.0 (N2), the other .Net 4.0 (N4).  They both contain the same `GetMessage()` function to return a string.

They are both registered using the .Net 4 **regasm** (.Net 2 **regasm** doesn't recognise the 4 assembly as being valid). If I create an instance of the N2 COM object all it good but creating an instance of the N4 COM object causes the bad behaviour.  In neither case to I invoke `GetMessage()`, I just create the COM object.

**Update:** 
It seems that the problem is .Net Version related.
On a machine with .Net 4.0 Client, the div/0 gives a stack overflow exception and then (on the second call) crashes. 
On a machine with .Net 4.5.1, I get a div/0 exception and everything is working fine.
Any ideas out there what might be different between how 4.5.1 and 4.0 (client) handle math co-processor exceptions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your code. Try doing some debugging, Ask yourself how the stack can be overflowing?

Comment: I'd have thought so but I have taken it out into a little test application.

Comment: I'm out of ideas now. I do think some narrowing down, and some hardcore debugging are likely to be needed. Good luck!

Comment: @David Heffernan, thanks for looking.  I was writing an edit to my comment and it timed out because I took too long. I was about to say  --I'd have thought so but I have created a little test application. All it contains is the machine code for a single calculation ->  1/0.  If I run this, I get my expected div by 0 exception.  If I add a line to the startup to create the COM Object (no other changes), the div by 0 becomes a stackoverflow and then a access violation.  I can't see anywhere that a stackoverflow might be occurring -- Again, thanks.

Comment: @AlanT What if you create a different COM Object - anything else, just something other than what you've written?  Something universally available would make a simple MCVE that you could add to your question - if, of course, it replicates the problem.  If not, then you can focus your attention on your C# code for ideas.

Comment: @J... Tried that. I have a simple COM object with a single method to return a string. I'll update the question with details.

Comment: Try masking floating point exceptions before you create the COM object with `Set8087CW($027F)`. And then unmask them later with `Set8087CW($1332)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Tried it. Still got bad behaviour but also some strangeness. If I call `Set8087CW($027F)` and immediately read the value it shows as $0277.  When I call `Set8087CW($1332)` and check the value, it shows as $1372.  ??

Comment: That's fine. There's a bit that is reserved that always comes back set. I guess you need to do more debugging.

Comment: Can you show `GetMessage`?

Comment: Yep. 'GetMessage()' returns correctly in both cases.